# Heist not substituting templates

Tags: haskell, heist

I have the following code, just copy-pasted and modernised (the original example does not compile with recent versions of Heist anymore) from [here](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2013-12-11-24-days-of-hackage-heist.html).

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Either
import Heist
import Heist.Compiled
import Blaze.ByteString.Builder


conf :: HeistConfig IO
conf =  set hcTemplateLocations [ loadTemplates "." ] $
        set hcInterpretedSplices defaultInterpretedSplices $
        emptyHeistConfig


runHeistConf :: Either [String] (HeistState IO) -> IO (HeistState IO)
runHeistConf (Right hs) = return hs
runHeistConf (Left msgs) = error . intercalate "\n" $ map ("[Heist error]: " ++) msgs


main :: IO ()
main = do
    heist <- id <$> (runEitherT $ initHeist conf) >>= runHeistConf
    output <- fst $ fromMaybe (error "xxx") $ renderTemplate heist "billy"

    BS.putStrLn . toByteString $ output
```

And the following template:

```
<!-- billy.tpl -->
<bind tag="wanted">Playstation 4</bind>
<bind tag="got">Monopoly board game</bind>

<apply template="letter">
  <bind tag="kiddo">Billy</bind>
  I regret to inform you the "<wanted />" you have requested is currently
  unavailable. I have substituted this with "<got />". I hope this does not
  disappoint you.
</apply>
```

Running this program outputs to the console the whole template (almost) as is. No substistutions are made. Probably there's some function call missing, required by modern Hesit versions. I was trying to track it down in the documentation, but no luck. Why doesn't it work?

Output:

```
<!-- billy.tpl --><bind tag='wanted'>Playstation 4</bind>&#10;<bind tag='got'>Monopoly board game</bind>&#10;
<apply template='letter'>
  <bind tag='kiddo'>Billy</bind>
  I regret to inform you the "<wanted></wanted>" you have requested is currently
  unavailable. I have substituted this with "<got></got>". I hope this does not
  disappoint you.
</apply>&#10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `renderTemplate` from `Heist.Compiled`, but defining interpreted splices.  I believe if you change this line:

```
set hcInterpretedSplices defaultInterpretedSplices
```

to this

```
set hcLoadTimeSplices defaultLoadTimeSplices
```

it should work

Comment: Indeed, it works now. Thanks a lot. But I'm somewhat cofused now by load-time splices and compiled splices. What's the actual difference between them? In the few tutorials I found on the internet, they wrote only about interpreted splices as opposed to compiled ones, so I just assumed that complied splices are the same as load-time splices. Apparently they're not the same though.

Comment: Check out the tutorial at http://snapframework.com/docs/tutorials/compiled-splices.  Specifically the paragraph that begins "To get around this problem we added the concept of load time splices".

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.